# Express.js - Access target route details in Application-level Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

#### Background:

I have an express application with some simple routes and Router-level Middleware. I want to register an Application-Level Middleware.

#### The Problem

In Router-Level Middlewares. I can access `req.route` object. But I can not access the same object inside an Application-Level Middleware.
I can understand this, as inside Application-Level middlewares the program is not inside the route yet.

But is there any way to get `req.route` object or something equivalent to `req.route.path` inside global middlewares?

`req.path` or `req.originalUrl` contains the real url not the route path.

#### Example

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3232;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const route = req.route; // It is an application level middleware, route is null
    return next(); 
});
app.get('/test/:someParams', (req, res) => {
    const route = req.route; // can access req.route here because it is a Router-level middleware

    console.log(route.path)
    console.log(req.path)
    return res.send('test')
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

#### Output

Request: GET@localhost:3232/test/33333

```
/test/33333 // I don't need this.
/test/:someParams // This is what I want to get inside the Application-Level Middleware
```

#### Alternative Solution

An alternative solution to this problem can be as the following

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3232;

function globalMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    const route = req.route;
    console.log(route) // can access it
    return next();
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const route = req.route; // It is an application level middleware, route is null

    return next();
});
app.get('/test/:someParams', globalMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    const route = req.route; // can access req.route here because it is a Router-level middleware
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

But injecting the same middleware to each and all of my routes does not sound like a smart solution. Specially on bigger applications.

#### A dump of router object

```
{ 
   "path":"/test/:someParams",
   "stack":[ 
      { 
         "name":"globalMiddleware",
         "keys":[ 

         ],
         "regexp":{ 
            "fast_star":false,
            "fast_slash":false
         },
         "method":"get"
      },
      { 
         "name":"<anonymous>",
         "keys":[ 

         ],
         "regexp":{ 
            "fast_star":false,
            "fast_slash":false
         },
         "method":"get"
      }
   ],
   "methods":{ 
      "get":true
   }
}
```

the `path` key is the thing I want to get. Please note that `req.route.path` is not the same as `req.path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this difficulty too. I didn't find anything on the internet that would solve it so I tried to search the express code itself for what it did to find the route. Basically it is the same thing as the code below, it looks for which regexp is valid for that route. (Google Translate)

```
const url = req.originalUrl.split('?')[0] // Routes with query
const layer = req.app._router.stack.find(layer => {
  return layer.regexp.exec(url) && layer.route
})
```

So you can access the original path:

```
console.log(layer.route.path)
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? If not, consider posting as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment I will look at this solution and I will set it as the true answer as I tested. I don't need this method anymore did this by some workaround. I will be very impressed if this works.

Comment: Confirmed. This is not a real solution but a nice workaround. May cause some performance issue for large applications as you loop over the stack and `regexp.exec` can sometimes be expensive. As Seems that there is no direct solution I accept this.

Comment: This solution is really an alternative. Only when I started to study the express code when you call the next function it performs practically the same thing, varying them all until you find it. And the same concern with performance came to me. Why is it really not a cool solution.

Comment: My latest APIs were made using NestJS that runs the express under the hood. And I needed to control each route and action. This was the only way I was able to do it. Which from what I understand is what you were proposing in your question. But concondor that for bigger applications something more should be thought.

Answer (score 0):

What data do you expect in req.route?

you can use `req.url`, `req.method`, `req.originalUrl`, etc...

or in Application level middleware you can add new field to `req` object

`req.customRoute = {yourField: "yourValue"}` 
and this field will available in route level middleware

Comment: I added some details for the sake of your question. Can you please read. By the way I don't want to add any fields to req.

Comment: why do you need get this: '/test/:someParams'?

Comment: Complicated. This will be a part of a global permission system I am writing for a project. this routes will be a small part of the system. Like X user has permission to access to `/test/:someParams`. This will be more complicated if I use `req.originalUrl`. `someParams` is changing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use middleware as per request

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    // Append what you want in req variable
    req.route = "abc"  // let abc
    req.path =  "path" // req.route.path
    next();
}
```

You can get it here from middleware

```
app.get('/test/:someParams', middleware, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.someParams)
    console.log(req.route) // "abc"
    console.log(req.path)  // "path"
});
```

For application level middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   req.route = "abc"  // let abc
   req.path = "path" // or req.route.path
   next()
})
```

Comment: Hi Ashok, I think there is a misunderstanding. I don't want to append anything to req. `req.route` is a native object of express which can be accessed inside Router-Level middlewares. but not Application-level middlewares. Can you please read my question again

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed you can't use application-level middleware you must use the router-level middleware till express version 4.17.1(which is latest version).